# Testing with mocha, Nightmare.js without ES6 syntax and yield

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, nightmare

I am using this question as example:

[Use Nightmare.js without ES6 syntax and yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589059/use-nightmare-js-without-es6-syntax-and-yield)

But if i put it in a mocha test this will go in a timeout, here the code:

```
describe('Google', function() {
it('should do things', function(done) {
    var x = Date.now();
    var nightmare = Nightmare();
    Promise.resolve(nightmare
        .goto('http://google.com')
        .evaluate(function() {
            return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
        }))
    .then(function(html) {
        console.log("done in " + (Date.now()-x) + "ms");
        console.log("result", html);
        expect(html).to.equal('abc');
        done();
        return nightmare.end();
    }).then(function(result) {

    }, function(err) {
        console.error(err); // notice that `throw`ing in here doesn't work
    });
});
});
```

But the problem is that `done()` is never called.

Answer (score 2):

I use mocha-generators plugin to do yield. Heres how I would structure your code:

```
require('mocha-generators').install();

var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('test login', function() { 

  var nightmare;

  beforeEach(function *() {
    nightmare = Nightmare({
      show: true,
    });

  afterEach(function*() {
    yield nightmare.end();
  });

  it('should go to google', function*() {
    this.timeout(5000);

    var result = yield nightmare
      .goto('http://google.com')
      .dosomeotherstuff

    expect(result).to.be('something')
  });

});
```

you don't need done if you are using generators since done is a callback that handles async

Comment: For me still does not work, when I run the `mocha test.js` It complains `beforeEach(function *() {
                        
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *`

Comment: @MaksimLuzik use newer version of node.js that supports generator syntax

Answer (score 0):

You should move the end after the .end() after the evaluate otherwise you'll get many errors like done() not called and also timeout because electron process do not close.

```
describe('Google', function() {
   it('should do things', function(done) {
    var x = Date.now();
    var nightmare = Nightmare();
    nightmare
        .goto('http://google.com')
        .evaluate(() => {
            return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
        })
        .end()
        .then( (html) => {
            console.log("done in " + (Date.now()-x) + "ms");
            console.log("result", html);
            expect(html).to.equal('abc');
            done();
        })
        .catch(done);
    });
});
```